# Error using Dialog API and Office.js

Tags: office-js

I am implementing a simple dialog window using examples from Office documentation (http://simonjaeger.com/lets-have-a-dialog-about-the-dialog-api/).

My code runs okay - although I'm just getting started.

In the Console I see the following error:

> TypeError: window.external.RegisterEvent is not a function. (In
>   'window.external.RegisterEvent(n,t,i,r)',
>   'window.external.RegisterEvent' is undefined)

The file with the error is:

```
/* Word Mac-specific API library */
/* Version: 16.0.8326.3000 */

/* Office.js Version: 16.0.8302.1000 */
/*
```

What prompts this? Should I do anything about it? My dialog closes okay (which seems to have been a problem on Macs in 2016).

I'm building on macOS running Word 15.35. I can share some code if I know where to look...here is the simple function to pop the dialog from my taskpane:

```js
$('#editDialogWindowBtn').click(function () {
    console.log('trying to open dialog to edit library...');

var dialogUrl = 'https://localhost/test/editLibraryDialog.html';

// Display the dialog.
Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync(dialogUrl, { width: 30, height: 30, requireHTTPS: true }, function (asyncResult) {
    if (asyncResult.status !== Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) {
        // TODO: Handle error.
        return;
    }

    // Get the dialog and register event handlers.
    var dialog = asyncResult.value;
    dialog.addEventHandler(Microsoft.Office.WebExtension.EventType.DialogMessageReceived, function (asyncResult) {
        if (asyncResult.type !== Microsoft.Office.WebExtension.EventType.DialogMessageReceived) {
            // TODO: Handle unknown message.
            return;
        }

        // Parse the message.
        var data = JSON.parse(asyncResult.message);
        showNotification('Hello #Office365Dev', data.name);

        // TODO: Do something with the data.

        // We got our data, time to close the dialog.
        dialog.close();
    });
  });

});
```

Comment: Are you getting this error when you run your app inside an Office application as an add-in?

Comment: Yes. Continually.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I've seen reports of this error when the add-in app code is run outside the context of Office, so thought it was worth checking whether or not that scenario aligned with what you're doing. I'll see if I can find out more about this particular error, and will update this thread if I'm able to identify any potential causes.

Comment: Cool - thanks. I haven't tried on Windows yet...will report back if I get the error there.

I have built a number of dialog windows and the error doesn't affect functionality, at least running locally. 

Do you consider it a benign error?